# need help in getting radio button being set properly

Tags: jquery, html

well i am trying to develop a web page so i have added a radio button in it.On click i get the values sorted.my problem is when i get the required answer the click i have done to get the value disappears,i need it to stay:

CODING:

```
var priceRangeFunction = function () {
            $(".priceRange").on("click", function () {
                    countPrizeRange=countPrizeRange+1;
                var priceSortFrom = $(this).attr("from");
                var priceSortTo = $(this).attr("to");
                conditions.push({
                        "range": {
                            "items.price": {
                                "gte": priceSortFrom,
                                "lte": priceSortTo
                            }
                        }
                    });
                console.log(conditions);
                search(0,conditions,featureConditions,customConditions);

            });
        };

        var priceRangeCustomiseFunction = function () {

            $(document).on('click', '#submitCustom', function (){
                    countPrizeRangeCheck=countPrizeRangeCheck+1;
                var customPriceFrom = $("#custom").val();
                var customPriceTo =$("#custom2").val();
                customConditions.push({
                        "range": {
                            "items.price": {
                                "gte": customPriceFrom,
                                "lte": customPriceTo
                            }
                        }
                    });
                console.log(conditions);
                search(0,conditions,featureConditions,customConditions);
                return false;

            });
        };
```

Comment: give us a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the problem you are facing.